# Data underlyng e GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView.
At event _RowDataBound I need take the underlying value from every single Field (ex let immagine FirstName), apply some logic to it, and display the field modify to a Textbox.

My problem is I do not the syntax to get the values connected with the e.Row.DataItmem for a single row.

Any idea how to do it? Please provide me an example of code. I posted this question in past but without understanding the answer. Thanks

```
switch (e.Row.RowType)
        {
            // In case type of row is DataRow (a data row of GridView) 
            case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                // What I add here?
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on the property names of the object you used as the gridvieww datasource, so if you had a column named FirstName, you can access it like this:

```
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
string name = row["FirstName"].ToString();
```

a better approach i always use is to cast the DataItem object itself to my bound class. for example if the gridview datasource is a `List<Employee>`, i do the following:

```
Employee item = (Employee) e.Row.DataItem;
```

then you can access all the properties using the item

Comment: Thanks, I tried your first code and I get an ERROR Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' .... any ideas??

Comment: im actually a vb.net developer and in vb.net i do the following, so if you can translate this: Dim name as String = e.Row.DataItem("FirstName")

Comment: i think in c# there is an additional cast that needs to be done

Comment: let me try it and i'll get back to you in a minute

Comment: DataRowView row =  (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem; string name = row["FirstName"].ToString();

Comment: i tried to use your new code an I receive {"Unable to cast object of type 'WebProject.Cms.DataAccess.CmsAuthor' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'."}

Comment: oh, then its better to use the other approach( cast the DataItem to CmsAuthor)

Comment: WebProject.Cms.DataAccess.CmsAuthor item = (WebProject.Cms.DataAccess.CmsAuthor) e.Row.DataItem;

Comment: ok that line is ok, but i get a second error: Error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'WebProject.Cms.DataAccess.CmsAuthor'

Comment: you dont use [] in this method. just use item.FirstName

Comment: ok finally i make it! it is working :-) thanks once again i really appreciated!